# what's the meaning of "take me off the speaker"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Carl, **take me off the speaker.** Did I tell you that these are house
>   seats?

I found this line from the movie, 'as good as it gets', and I'm curious about this phrase 'take me off the speaker'. I guess it means 'turn off the speaker mode', but I don't get how it makes such meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a phone call, a person who says "take me off speaker" wants to say something that only the other person should hear and not anyone who might be within earshot of the phone's loud-speaker.  It means "turn off the phone's speaker and hold the phone to your ear". The pronoun "me" there refers to himself as the identify of the person whose voice is coming out of the phone's speaker on the other end.

If you understand all of this already, then your question is not about language but about the movie.

Comment: I think this's still a language question. The movie is just the context

Comment: And what is it about the phrase that puzzles you? Did I guess correctly when I figured it was the pronoun "me"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I just comment on the last sentence. Nothing puzzles me here, nor I am telling you something is wrong.